# HttpRequest.UrlReferrer does not appear to exist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application which uses MVC4, but now realised it really should be a Web API and as such I'm moving over to a ASP.NET 4.5.2 web API 2 project.

The problem is, where I was using `Request.ServerVariables[]` in my MVC project I have been advised that it's not the 'correct' way in a Web API, as such, I should be using `Request.RequestUrl`

The example on the MSDN is simply

```
 Uri MyUrl = Request.UrlReferrer;  //kaboom for me
 Response.Write("Referrer URL Port: " + Server.HtmlEncode(MyUrl.Port.ToString()) + "<br>");
 Response.Write("Referrer URL Protocol: " + Server.HtmlEncode(MyUrl.Scheme) + "<br>");
```

The issue is, despite referencing `System.Web` there is no property for `Request` are  `UrlReferrer` - the only properties are `Content`, `Headers`, `Method`, `Properties`, `RequestUri` and `Version`.
Why can't I use `Request.UrlReferrer` as per the [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)?

Comment: Can you link to the MSDN example please, so we can see more context? Are you sure it's a WebAPI example? Note that web API methods are usually *static* methods, whereas in MVC you'd write *instance* methods which therefore have access to instance properties... I suspect `Request` is just an instance property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you just need to get the current request in a different way, due to being in a static method rather than in a context where you can refer to a `Request` instance property:

```
var request = HttpContext.Current;
var referrer = request.UrlReferrer;
...
```